# Special chapter title formatting

Tags: sectioning, horizontal-alignment, formatting, titlesec

Using the `book` class. I would like to have chapter titles that look like this:

```
|                      CHAPTER ## |
| Chapter Title (italic)          |
```

Can `titlesec` do this?

Answer (score 6):

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
    {\raggedleft\normalfont\LARGE\bfseries}{\MakeUppercase{\chaptertitlename}\ \thechapter}
    {20pt}{\raggedright\Huge\itshape}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Chapter title}

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}​
```

[image]